# Direct link of vimeo android

Tags: android, video, android-videoview, vimeo, vimeo-api

I have a video view which is able to stream video, plus I have pro account. where I can upload trailers (movies). I need anyone to help,how can I get direct link of video which is possible to load in video view. I have explored some method like to load video in **webview** which I really don't want. so help me out in loading it in videoview.

link which I want to stream in native video view

[Link](https://vimeo.com//123406533)

Comment: Can you show some code that you've wrote already?

Comment: I did sort out solution. below is pasted. if anyone in a need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get a direct link of vimeo video, which you can pass to any player.
Here's the method:
first hit on to this link https://player.vimeo.com/video/[VIDEO_ID]/config
you get a json responce.you can parse json this way

```
String URL = json.getJSONObject("request")
    .getJSONObject("files")
    .getJSONObject("h264")
    .getJSONObject("sd").getString("url");
```

Now the output string "URL" can be used in any player. which is actually a direct link to stream video.

Comment: This is an unsupported method of accessing video files, and will break at the whim of Vimeo's developers. The only official way of accessing video files is from the website in the video settings, or through the API.

Answer (score 2):

PRO members can access their video files in any video response in the API. You can read more about the API here: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/start.

Video responses are returned from single video requests (`/videos/{video_id}`) or collection requests (authenticated user's videos: `/me/videos`).

You can find the links under the `files` key of the JSON response.

**Note:** Any other way of accessing source files is unsupported by Vimeo, and will lead to your app breaking unexpectedly without any advance notice.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Dashron, a more scalable approach would be to use the [Vimeo API](https://developer.vimeo.com/api).

We've built a Java/Android library that will make accessing your video file URL's a lot easier. You can get the library setup by following the [the README](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-networking-java#vimeo-networking) of the library.

`compile 'com.vimeo.networking:vimeo-networking:1.0.1'`

Then when you've made a request for your videos, you'll be able to access the files on the [`Video` object](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-networking-java/blob/dev/vimeo-networking/src/main/java/com/vimeo/networking/model/Video.java).

`Video.files.get(...).link` (note that only authenticated PRO users have access to the files field).

Using the library will ensure that you always have access to this `link` URL. Getting the JSON from the config, as you have as your accepted answer, is subject to breaking at any point.

If you have any further questions, please file them in our [issues](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-networking-java/issues) section of the library github.